# How to perform a seamless upgrade inside a Kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

I'd like to add a seamless upgrade capability to a Kubernetes operator which manages a distributed database. Is there some good practices to do that?

Particularly, on the configuration side, here is my CR.yaml:

```
apiVersion: qserv.lsst.org/v1alpha1
kind: Qserv
metadata:
  name: qserv
spec:
  czar:
    image: qserv/qserv:v1.0.0
    replicas: 1
  storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  worker:
    image: qserv/qserv:v1.0.0
    replicas: 2
```

Shall I perform database schema upgrade it when the container image tag changes in my `CR.yaml` file?
Shall I add a "performDatabaseUpgrade=true" field in my `CR.yaml`?
Or is there other techniques, like creating an additional CRD?

In addition, is there a recommended way to implement this inside the `operator-sdk` framework?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first approach you mention, changing the container image when the tag changes in the CR.yaml.

About how to implement this, I prefer to perform a check, create, validate and update cycle inside the reconcile loop for each operand following this steps:

1. `check`: if the operand exists and that the owner reference matches the custom resource.
2. `create`: if the operand doesn't exists create a new one.
3. `validate` the operand configuration matches the custom resource. (For example, compare the Docker image of a pod with the custom resource.)
4. `update` if you detect any difference in the `validate` step.